# ARRAY[T, SIZE] Appropriate Default Constructor Available

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

template<class T, int SIZE>
class Array
{
private:
    T array[SIZE];
public:
    T& operator[](int nIndex)
    {
        return array[nIndex];
    }
 };

template<class T1, class T2> 
class Pairs
{
private:
    T1 first;
    T2 second; T2 third;
public:
    Pairs(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) : 
        first(t1), second(t2)
    {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
   Array<Pairs<int, int>, 40> sample;

   sample[0] =  Pairs <int, int> (40, 20);

   return 0;
}
```

I am fairly new to C++. Just tried something with templates and getting the:

```
error: ARRAY<T,SIZE>: no appropriate default constructor available.
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `Pairs` doesn't have a default constructor. An instance of `Array< Pairs<int, int>, 40>` needs to construct 40 instances of `Pairs` - but there's no constructor to do that with.

If you want `Pairs` to be usable in an `Array`, give it a default constructor (one with no parameters).